# How to calculate the distance between two markers in leaflet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, dom-events

I am using **leaflet** under **Angularjs**.
At the leaflet map I have two markers **m1** and **m2**. 
The map and the distance between the two markers are displayed using the following directives.

```
<leaflet ng-mouseup="change()" center="cen" paths="paths" markers="markers"></leaflet>
{{dist}}
```

I want to calculate/recalculate the distance any time a marker is moved.
For doing this I wrote a function **change()** which is called when the event **ng-mouseup** is triggered.

The corresponding **js** is as follows:

```
$scope.dist = distance($scope.markers.m1.lat, $scope.markers.m2.lat, 
                       $scope.markers.m1.lng, $scope.markers.m2.lng);   

$scope.change = function() {            
     $scope.dist = distance($scope.markers.m1.lat, $scope.markers.m2.lat, 
                            $scope.markers.m1.lng, $scope.markers.m2.lng);  
};
```

The function **change** is called when a marker is moved and this function is calling the function **distance**  *but* not with the new values of the markers. The original (old) values of the marker are passed.

The question is how I can get the distance between the two markers using the **new** position of the marker instead.

EDIT: Here is the jsfiddle code.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/vg01q7xw/

Comment: Can you provide plunker/jsfiddle/codepen ?

Comment: seems that your leaflet directive does not update markers. Could you post this directive?

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vg01q7xw/